# configure .htaccess to use a subfolder as root and mask the url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've been trying several solutions in the internet and can't make the redirect voodoo to work.

### Setup

My setup is a website build with jekyll, and I want to consume it as `mydomain.com/~user`.

The folder structure is

```
~user
  - _site
    - index.html
    - folder1
      - index.html
    - folder2
      - index.html
  - other_stuff
```

### Problem

I was able to redirect from `mydomain.com/~user` to `mydomain.com/~user/_site`. So, half way through. The problem came when I tried to mask and remove the `_site` from the URL again. And I hit a wall.

Basically I want to use: `mydomain.com/~user` and see that URL in the browser, while beeing served the page that lives in `mydomain.com/~user/_site/index.html`. And same goes for other links

```
Request                    See                         Served
=======                    =======                     =======
mydomain.com/~user         mydomain.com/~user          mydomain.com/~user/_site/
mydomain.com/~user/folder1 mydomain.com/~user/folder1  mydomain.com/~user/_site/folder1
```

### What I try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/~user/_site/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~user/_site/$1


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule !^~user/_site(.*)$ /~user/_site$1 [L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^~user/_site(.*)$ /~user$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule !^~user/_site(.*)$ /~user/_site$1 [L]
```

However, all these

- Do not end with the desired hidden URL in the bar
- Give an error, as some of the redirects are not allowed in the server

### Partial solution

After tweaking the [proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39156569/424986), I was able to identify one variation that partially works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~user
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_site/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _site/$1 [L]
```

Note that in the last two line, i remove the `~user` from the regex. This redirects all subfolders and pages, and allows other folders that are in `~user` to be accessed.

However, the "home" `mydomain.com/~user` is the only one that is not redirected. As it exists the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` doesn't allow it to be processed.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ _site/ [L]
```

To redirect the home (`~user`) to `mydomain/~user/_site`, but it doesn't work. And tried variations of `^/?$` and `^$`. But they don't work either.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should try it this way.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/~user/_site/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^~user/(.*)$ /~user/_site/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You never actually said what issue you were having when you tried your rules. You probably have indexing turned on. You need this at the top of your .htaccess file `Options -Indexes`

Comment: The problem is that I can't remove the `_site`, and when I try I just get an internal server error. The issue is that the server is managed by a third party and shared. So, I don't have much control on the configuration. I tried adding the option, but I get an internal error too.

Comment: Further testing shows that links other than `mydomain.com/~user` actually are redirected. But when I access the previous address I get the listing of the directory instead. But, for some reason some links work, and others don't. I can't see a pattern on what some folders have that can be accessed and others won't.